# Issue with opening Oracle VM Virtualbox in Windows 10

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have installed Oracle VM Virtalbox. I face the below error when i try to open the application
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulkLs.png)

Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object.

The application will now terminate.

Completely failed to instantiate CLSID_VirtualBox: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE.

Result Code: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005)
Component: VirtualBoxClientWrap
Interface: IVirtualBoxClient {d2937a8e-cb8d-4382-90ba-b7da78a74573}

Note: If i restart my machine it works. but if i close virtual box and open it, same error happens

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar issue before

Comment: I had exactly the same scenario. Even closing VirtualBox still leaves one of the background processes (VBoxSDS) running.

Answer (score 3):

Ending the background process **VBoxSDS** in the Task Manager (Ctrl + Alt + Del) allowed me to restart VirtualBox without the error.